# How to print usage and help from all argparser objects?

Tags: python, argparse

I have multiple `ArgumentParser()` in my python script. However, when I run it with `-h` help is printed only for the first argparser whose arguments got parsed.

code:

```
%%writefile ./test_argparse.py
import argparse
ap1 = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap1.add_argument("-a", "--abcd", help="help a")
var1 = ap1.parse_known_args()
ap2 = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap2.add_argument("-e", "--efgh", help="help e")
var2 = ap2.parse_known_args()
```

in shell run:

```
python test_argparse.py --help
```

output:

```
usage: test_argparse.py [-h] [-a ABCD]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -a ABCD, --abcd ABCD  help a
```

As you can see the usage and help both are displayed only for `ap1`

I want to be able to display usage and help for both argparsers: `ap1` and `ap2`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: `ap2.print_help()`

Comment: Why are you creating multiple argparsers?

Comment: @Marc - Thank you for asking. My script would be constructing 2 classes. I wanted 1 set of parameters to be passed to the constructor of one class and the other set of parameters to be passed to the constructor of the second class. I would use ```params_class1 = {k:v for k,v in vars(ap1.parse_known_args()[0]).items() if v}``` to make the parameters dictionary and pass them as ```**params_class1``` to the constructor. Any better ideas?

Comment: @hpaulj - Thank you for your response! As I see it, your sugestion would help me create a scenario where the script can print help for all the argparsers when no input is specified along with the script and even in that case the usage and help would be fragmented for each argparser not giving a complete picture in one go. Can I generate the entire help and usage when specifying the ```-h``` option?

Comment: why two parsers? Are you looking for `add_subparsers` method?

Comment: The `help` action bound to `-h` by default exits the script; your second parser never gets used.

Answer (score 0):

Try run file using such way. It works:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('target_1', metavar='TARGET', help='Test1')
parser.add_argument('target_2', metavar='TARGET2', help='Test2')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: This does not answer the question

Answer (score 0):

Argparse has this concept of "[subparsers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers)" and that might do what you want? If you think about `git` or similar commands where the first thing is the command `git` and the next thing is some sub-command (like `push` or `pull` or `clone`) and each of those subcommands has its own set of possible arguments, you can achieve that using subparsers.

First you create a subparser for each of your subcommands, then you do the same sort of `add_argument()` to each subparser. I'm pretty sure when you print usage it will print all the help for all your subcommands.